# using ngModel inside a for loop without an actual variable in the class

Tags: angular, validation

I'm not sure if this is possible but wanted to know.  I have the following template (extracted)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let items of items; let index = index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <div>
        <div 
            [ngClass]="{'error':cat.invalid && (cat.dirty || cat.touched)}">
            <input type="text" name="subName" 
                [(ngModel)]="catName" #cat="ngModel" required />               
        </div>
    </div>
 </ng-container>
```

My problem is with the `ngModel`.  In this scenario I actually have a variable named `catName` in the .ts file and this ends up all the items in the loop sharing the same variable and value. I'm only using `ngModel` to determine the `invalid, dirty, touched` state to display an error. I can introduce a new collection in the .ts file and try to bind `ngModel` to items in that collection, however I prefer to do this without introducing a variable in the .ts file.  Is there an alternative way I can use to get this done.  Basically I want to know the state of the control `valid, dirty, touched` and then display an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have template variable `#cat` which can tell you, if control has value or not but it doesn't have `touch` or `dirty` properties, so without `ngModel` it wouldn't know if control has been touched or not.

In your case, if you just don't want to have a variable in .ts file then you can use following -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let items of items; let index = index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <div>
        <div 
            [ngClass]="{'error':cat.invalid && (cat.dirty || cat.touched)}">
            <input type="text" name="subName" 
                [(ngModel)]="index" #cat="ngModel"  required />               
        </div>
    </div>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks for this and it does fix the issue, however I am using the index property not shown here for another purpose to access the collection.  Therefore if I use `[(ngModel)]=index` that would end up overriting the index value ?  I tried to declare another variable in the for loop like `*ngFor="let items of items; let index = index; let otherVar=''` however that broke the flow.